# Python unittest ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I've been trying to test a simple program I wrote in python 3.8 using the built-in unittest module and a python virtual environment.

This is my project's directory structure:

```
Project
├── .venv
├── src
│   ├── my_class.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── utils.py
├── test
│   └── test_my_class.py
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

With the virtual environment activated, I can't properly execute the test_my_class.py file in the recommended way through: `python -m unittest test.test_my_class.Tester` as it gives me the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_my_class (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_my_class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.test_my_class'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

If I run it as `python ./test/test_my_class.py` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test/test_my_class.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src.my_class import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Only when I run it as `PYTHONPATH=. python ./test/test_my_class.py` it works.

I've search SO for similar issues but none of the suggestions helped.

What is the proper way to test a python script while using a virtual environment?
In addition, how can I make vscode recognize the imported file without giving an error?

Comment: Maybe put `main.py` in `Project` or `test` in `src`.

Comment: The proper way would be to let `unittest` discover tests in the package `test`, rather than executing the test script directly: `python -m unittest test`, for example.

Comment: @chepner If I run it like that it works! But the tutorial I was following suggested to specify the testfile and class too (to run just that file when you have multiple files). Why ins't that working?

Comment: Because the directory containing the script is added to the Python search path, not the current working directory. If `test`, rather than `.`, is on the search path, Python won't find `src`.

Comment: @chepner that's not what I asked. I asked why test works but test.test_my_class does not

Comment: @chepner never mind. With python -m unittest test it is still not working, it says it run 0 tests

Answer (score -1):

> python -m unittest test.test_my_class.Tester

There is an error in your run test command. This is clearly stated in the comments:

> python -m unittest test

Of course, there is another solution. You can use the test framework in vscode to let it scan by itself.

By default, the Python extension attempts to discover tests once you enable a framework. You can trigger test discovery at any time using the **Test: Refresh Tests** command.

You can refer to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_test-discovery) for more details.

Comment: It is clearly stated in the comments that "python -m unittest test" also does not work. Furthermore, it is not wrong to use "test.test_my_class.Tester" as you are claiming

Comment: Is pytest valid?